# Difference between permission-tree and permission-group?

Tags: android, android-permissions

What is the difference between `permission-tree` and `permission-group` in Android?

Comment: @Lucifer So linking to google is your way welcoming a new user? This made it even worse... back to the OP: I voted to close that question as it is really hard to get what you want. We will not guide you through the official resources. Please see the [FAQ] for detailed information on how to ask here.